# why momentjs returns a wrong minutes from a diff?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I try to calculate a diff between hours and minutes using moment.

for example I want to calculate the diff between: 8:00 and 18:00 (should be 10:00).

But in my code it come out `totalMinutes = 600`. why?

```
const xin = '8:00';
const xout = '18:00';

const a = moment(xin, 'HH:mm');
const b = moment(xout, 'HH:mm');

const totalHours = moment.duration(b.diff(a)).asHours();
const totalMinutes = moment.duration(b.diff(a)).asMinutes();

console.log({ r: `${totalHours}:${totalMinutes}` });

// 10:600
```

Comment: what do you expect it to be? since different is 10 hours the equivalent will be 600 mins? Wouldn't it?

Comment: maybe I doing it wrong. I expected to 00. as 10:00.

Comment: I have added an answer. Hopefully that should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get diff in hours and minutes which wouldn't give the expected result as they are same thing in different unit. convert them to milisecond, wrap them in moment and format.

```
const moment = require("moment");
const xin = "8:00";
const xout = "18:00";

const a = moment(xin, "HH:mm");
const b = moment(xout, "HH:mm");

const duration = moment.utc(moment.duration(b.diff(a)).asMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm");


console.log(duration);
```